# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS constant internal server errors

Tags: 12.04

my problem seems to be too overarching for me to be able to be very specific, but basically, today after installing some updates through the update manager, Ubuntu suddenly became very slow and starter freezing if I tried to open a new browser tab, or open a file in LibreOffice from a folder, anything. An error message arrived that something had gone wrong with Nautilus. I restarted a bunch of times, in recovery mode and then in normal mode when prompted. Everything is unbelievably slow (takes more than 10 minutes for the GUI to launch whereas before today it took 1 at most), pretty much nothing apart from Chrome or Firefox will open in the GUI - instead, internal server error messages arrive.
At one point I was prompted to look for unmet dependencies and seem to have eliminated those successfully, installed all possible updates and upgrades from the terminal (after a few restarts, the graphic Update Manager started up again and would have installed some updates to the virtual filesystem if it hadn't closed, I think those are installed now through Terminal as well.) Nothing changed following the updates.
The only piece of advice I've gotten so far is to just install Ubuntu 15.04 and be done with it, but I would desperately like to avoid that for the time being and get 12.04 LTS to work properly with programs actually launching for just a little while longer and/or to find the cause of the problem, if there is one other than having an outdated version. Thanks in advance for any help on such a messy issue.